# How to integrate PostgreSql with EntityFramework 6.0.2?

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-6

I am receiving following error

> The 'Instance' member of the Entity Framework provider type
>   'Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql, Version=2.0.14.2, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7' did not return an object that
>   inherits from 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices'.
>   Entity Framework providers must inherit from this class and the
>   'Instance' member must return the singleton instance of the provider.
>   This may be because the provider does not support Entity Framework 6
>   or later; see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more
>   information.

Can any one help me

here is my App.Config File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CacsLocal" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=Kappa;User Id=postgres; Password=xyz;" providerName="Npgsql" />
    <add name="   CacsCentral" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=KPT1;User Id=postgres; Password=insane1234;" providerName="Npgsql" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>     
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"></provider>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description="Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

I have Npgsql2 version 2.0.14.2
Entity Framework 6.0.2

All the packages are installed through Package Manager by following command

```
Install-Package Npgsql -Pre
Install-Package EntityFramework -Pre
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have [this reference] in your Main project(http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/)?

Comment: let me check and do it again

Comment: One thing, don't use the `-pre` versions. You might get some incompatibilities.

Comment: after using this reference I am getting this error "The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'NPGSQL' is either not registered in the machine or application config file" Inner exception shows Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed

Comment: Uninstall everything and install it again. Use the npgsql forums as well

Comment: Uninstall what .. ? I download the library and added as a reference ..what seems to be the problem

Comment: The library, the PostgreSql provider should set the App.config

Comment: I dont have the installer of npgsql

Comment: Suggest me a solution Tico

Comment: You need to install it.

Comment: From where I can get the installer Please suggest

Comment: Your error message is suggesting that you are using an EF5 provider with EF6 and this is not supported. You need to install an EF6 provider.

Comment: I have installed the EF6 provider friend let me share you the link http://pgfoundry.org/frs/?group_id=1000140 check the ef6 version i have downloaded this one

Comment: can you please forward me the link of EF6 provider

Comment: Did you find the solution? I have the same problem too.

Comment: Yes I have found the solution :)

Comment: @Shakoor Alam - could you kindly elaborate on which file at [this site](http://pgfoundry.org/frs/?group_id=1000140) is the EF6 provider and how you "installed" it?

Comment: Hi @sevzas! Please, check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066702/entity-framework-6-with-npgsql to get it working. I hope it helps. Please let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

In **App.config** file insert this code befoere the <system.data>

```
<!--PostgreSQL Connection-->
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="PGConnectionString" connectionString="Host=localhost;DataBase=codefirst;User Id=postgres;Password=Sanju0212@;" providerName="Npgsql" />
   </connectionStrings>
```

run few commands on package manager console
1.Enable-Migration
2. Add-Migration
3. Update-database -verbose